# Wrong protrusion with csquotes and microtype

Tags: margins, punctuation, microtype, csquotes, protrusion

I’m experiencing problems using the [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package and [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) using protrusion (margin kerning). The problem is that using `\enquote` I only get margin kerning on the left margin.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[tracking]{microtype}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{»}{«}

\begin{document}
\def\blindtext{Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen, Testen, Testen und Testen von Textausgaben und anderen Zeichen}

\noindent%
„\blindtext.“ \blindtext{} in mehreren Zeilen.\\
\enquote{\blindtext.} \blindtext{} in mehreren Zeilen.\\
»\blindtext.« \blindtext{} in mehreren Zeilen.\\
\end{document}
```

The first text uses manually set quotation marks which give margin kerning both left *and* right.

The second and third text snipped only protrude on the left margin.

Any ideas why I have this problem and how I can possibly solve it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd regard this as a bug in `csquotes`. You can solve it by putting the following code into your preamble, but I can't say if this breaks other things.

```
\makeatletter
\def\csq@qclose@ii#1{%
  \ifdim\lastkern=\csq@omitmarker
    #1\csq@eqgroup
  \else
    \csq@addkern@close
    \ifodd\csq@qlevel
      \csq@thequote@oclose
      \let\csq@kernchar@i\csq@thequote@oclose
    \else
      \csq@thequote@iclose
      \let\csq@kernchar@i\csq@thequote@iclose
    \fi
    %\csq@setmarker@close                 %%% Here's the change; line commented out
    \ifblank{#1}{}{\expandafter#1}%
    \expandafter\csq@eqgroup
      \expandafter\def
      \expandafter\csq@kernchar@i
      \expandafter{\csq@kernchar@i}%
    \expandafter\csq@fixkern
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

This works with the most recent version of `csquotes`. As always, when you hack into the macros of a package, there's no guarantee that the above code works with past or future versions.

Comment: Thanks. But this seems to only work with the latest updates in TexLive 2010.

Comment: @Debilski: Thanks for letting me know. I've added a word of caution to the answer.

Comment: However, there is a `\def\csq@qclose@i` in earlier versions with almost the same code (except that it takes no argument). Patching that one works as well. Bad thing is that newer versions have both `\csq@qclose@ii` *and* `\csq@qclose@i` (which looks rather different) so one definitely has to be careful to patch the correct one.

Comment: @Debilski: I have no idea if you'd also have to patch the other one. I just tried to make the code from your question produce the desired result; I'm not sure if there are more "margin bugs".

Comment: @Debilski, it may be a good idea to drop an email to Philipp, to let him know of this issue (or post on comp.text.tex _and_ email him).

Comment: Done.​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Ok, so Philipp has answered and said that the marker is needed for some features and that there might not be a way to fix this in csquotes.

Comment: @Debilski: Hmm, now I would be interested _what_ it is needed for. What I'd recommend in the present situation: If it really happens that you've got a closing quote at the end of a line, then as a final change in the document use my code _locally_ so that it only affects that quote. If you don't know how to do that, you could ask a new question here.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Is this issue still valid in 2017?

Comment: @Hotschke: I just came here to ask this question in 2018! So we still have the problem. Workaround can also be condensed to `\renewcommand*{\csq@setmarker@close}{}`.

Comment: Emptying both `\csq@setmarker@close` and `\csq@setmarker@open` will also enable kerning with both quotes. I guess what we are disabling could be related to neighboring quotation marks and [french auto spacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_orthography#Punctuation)?