# AUCTeX's csquotes integration does not work together with babel

Tags: emacs, incompatibility, babel, auctex, csquotes

I use [the AUCTeX feature](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Quotes.html) to expand <kbd>"</kbd> into `csquotes` macros. To enable it I have put the following in my .emacs:

```lisp
;; " expands into csquotes macros
(setq LaTeX-csquotes-close-quote "}"
      LaTeX-csquotes-open-quote "\\enquote{")
```

However, when I use it together with `babel` <kbd>"</kbd> is not expanded to `csquotes` macros.

For instance, pressing <kbd>"</kbd> in the following example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

results in

> "`

Here is a screenshot of when I press <kbd>"</kbd> inside the `document` environment:

[image: Screenshot of what happens when I press "]

What I would like to happen is that `\enquote{` is inserted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For it to work you have to load `babel` *after* `csquotes` as reported in http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.auctex.bugs/1850.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Now pressing <kbd>"</kbd> will correctly expand to `\enquote{`:

[image: Screenshot of the working expansion]