# Smart Quotes Control in AucTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex

If I have the statement `\usepackage{ngerman}` in my source-code AucTeX recognizes this and inserts correct german quotation marks if I press " twice. For example

```
"`a german quote"'
```

How can I make this work without having a `\usepackage{ngerman}` statement in my source?

A. locally in my current buffer and

B. globally?

Is it possible to control this with a local emacs variable which I write in my document file?

Comment: it's a good idea to get rid of 15-yr-old `ngerman` package. If you're using `[ngerman]{babel}` instead, I suggest you also use `csquotes` and have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39575/auctexs-csquotes-integration-does-not-work-together-with-babel

Answer (score 1):

As nearly always, someone has written a package in lisp. Well, to be correct, as nearly always some people have contributed different packages. Have a look and decide, which one you like (did not test myself):

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TypographicalPunctuationMarks