# Why csquotes does not seem to be persistent?

Tags: csquotes

Using the `\hyphenblockcquote` like in  [What's the advantage of using csquotes over using an editor's auto-replacement for "?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39285/whats-the-advantage-of-using-csquotes-over-using-an-editors-auto-replacement-f/39302#39302)  seems (for a bloody beginner) not persistent. Inside the same section (another subsection, see below) the '`blockquote`' changes into a kind of `USenglish` 'style'.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % for writing other that basic characters
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[UKenglish, USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes} % blockquotation and other.
\usepackage{enumitem} % enumerate [1], [2],.. http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem

% Include any extra LaTeX packages required
\usepackage[authoryear, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the
                                                                % references in the Bibliography

\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
% \usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths

    \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

    @article{walton2012,
       author = {Walton, Douglas},
       title = {Using Argumentation Schemes for Argument Extraction: A Bottom-Up Method},
       journal = {Int. J. Cogn. Inform. Nat. Intell.},
       issue_date = {July 2012},
       year = {2012},
       }

    \end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\chapter{TeXperiments} % history of the jetpak

\section{Argumentation Theory}
\hyphenblockcquote{**UKenglish**}[p. 5]{emeren1996}{Argumentation is a verbal and social activity
of reason aimed at increasing (or decreasing) the acceptability of a controversial standpoint
for the listener or reader, by putting forward a constellation of propositions intended to
justify (or refute) the standpoint before a rational judge.}

\subsection{Walton's Argument Schemes}
Walton proposed the analysis of arguments with \textit{presumptive argumentation schemes}
\citep[p. 3]{walton1996}.

\hyphenblockcquote{**UKenglish**}[p. 34]{walton2012}{Argumentation schemes represent stereotypical
patterns of reasoning used in everyday conversational argumentation, as well as in a variety
of other contexts as well, [...] that aim at a decision on what to do in given circumstances.}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! I cannot reproduce the behavior in your picture with the MWE you provided. Both block quotes have the same format.

Comment: @jon reproducible example added :)

Comment: For me the example produces American-style quotation marks (66-99) for the shorter quotes (and a indented block quote for the longer). Maybe you need to update your TeX distribution (though `csquotes` has been stable for quite some time).

Comment: @jon A+! Awsome! Big Thanks! That's it. It works. Do you think it is useful to answer the question separately?

Comment: @alex You need to put the language you want as default last in the babel options: `\usepackage[USenglish,UKenglish]{babel}` will give you british style quotes.

Comment: @jon I removed not essential parts. Also some of my comments. If you want to post the Answer I would recommend it as the solution, and rate it. Thank You! :)

Comment: OK, I removed the comments and put the relevant part in an answer.

Comment: @cgnieder Hello :) Thank you for your help. As you can see Jon found the answer. We saw that there were pretty much comments on the question post that would not help others when trying to understand the issue. So we deleted some messages which would distract the reader. Can you please review your posts. Wish you a nice day :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The package `csquotes` can be responsible for deciding when it is necessary to switch from an in-line quotation to a 'block' or 'display' format.  For this to work, you need to use the quotation commands it provides that are designed to to this --- notably those commands that have `block` in their name:

- `\blockquote`
- `\foreignblockquote`
- `\hyphenblockquote`
- `\hybridblockquote`
- `\blockcquote`
- `\foreignblockcquote`
- `\hyphenblockcquote`
- `\hybridblockcquote`

Style guides tend to have their own views about how long a quotation needs to be before it must be a block quote, but `csquotes` defaults to `threshold=3` and `thresholdtype=lines`, which means more than three lines of quotation will be set as a block quotation.  You can change it to a word-threshold with `thresholdtype=words` (but then you probably don't want the `threshold` to be 3!).

Other important options to be aware of in this connection are:

- `parthreshold` (default: true): any quotation with an explicit paragraph or line break will trigger a block quotation; and
- `csdisplay` (default: false): by default, only inline quotations will be used in footnotes, parboxes, minipages, and floats.

And, of course, much of the default functionality is very customizable...