# Customizing style of formal block quote in csquotes?

Tags: quoting, csquotes

The MWE below:

```
% pdflatex test.tex; biber test; pdflatex test.tex; pdflatex test.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[autostyle=tryonce,autopunct=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  style=ieee,
  isbn=true,
  doi=false,
  url=true,
  defernumbers=true,
  sorting=nyt,
  %sorting=none, % "Do not sort at all. All entries are processed in citation order." (order of appearance)
  firstinits=false, % shows full first name
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[UKenglish,USenglish]{babel}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
% @book{knuth:ct:a,
%   author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
%   title        = {The \TeX book},
%   date         = 1984,

\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{yellow!10}

% [http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=5444 csquotes package question • Text Formatting • LaTeX Community]
% \renewenvironment{quoteblock}{\openautoquote}{\closeautoquote} % quoteblock has been removed from csquotes!
% \renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{\openautoquote{\itshape#1#2}#4#3\closeautoquote} % <--! works, but changes all

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39285/whats-the-advantage-of-using-csquotes-over-using-an-editors-auto-replacement-f
\begin{document}

\hyphenquote{UKenglish}{quote with UK English hyphenation}

\textcquote[1]{knuth:ct:a}{formal quote}

\hyphentextcquote{UKenglish}[1]{knuth:ct:a}{formal quote with UK English hyphenation}

\hyphenblockcquote{UKenglish}[1]{knuth:ct:a}{A long formal quote with UK English hyphenation which happens to be longer than three lines and, thus, is typeset as a block quote. This text is just to make it long enough. This text is just to make it long enough. This text is just to make it long enough.}

\printbibliography[sorting=none]

\end{document}
```

... currently produces this output:

[image: test.png]

What I'd like to get, is a block quotation that starts and ends with the right quotation marks, the text inside is styled italic, and the italic stops before the bibliography citation; that is:

[image: testb.png]

... which I can get by uncommenting the line marked with `<--!`, that is, `\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{\openautoquote{\itshape#1#2}#4#3\closeautoquote}`. This command, however, changes a relatively low-level `\mkblockquote` command.

So what I'd like to do now, is to have the default behavior of `\hyphenblockcquote` unchanged, and have a sort of a customized formal block quote environment instead. Ideally, I'd like to have a sort of a style option that I could use with `\hyphenblockcquote` - but if that is impossible, then I'd settle for a custom command (with a similar syntax like `\hyphenblockcquote`).

What would be the `csquotes` recommended way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, apparently what I wanted was a feature not yet implemented. I think I managed to solve it somewhat:

[image: test1.png]

... the MWE is below, and it required definitions and use of new user commands, `\DeclareQuoteBlockStyle` and `\setquoteblockstyle`. However, some discussion may be in order.

- All this business with inner and outer quoting is **only** possible if you use `\enquote{...}` inside your e.g. `\hyphentextcquote`; I thought it was doable also by defining characters via `\MakeOuterQuote`/`\MakeAutoQuote` - but it seems not.
- When you make a style in `\DeclareQuoteStyle`, it is by default **not** "applied" anywhere - unless you happen to alias it with the same name as a currently chosen language.
- In order to "apply"/"activate" such a quote style, you cannot use `\ExecuteQuoteOptions` or `\setkeys`, as they run only in preamble; there is actually a command for that, and it is `\setquotestyle`
- When you use `csquotes`' `\DeclareQuoteAlias[variant]{style}{alias}`, note that you can use the `alias` **only** in `\setquotestyle{alias}`; you can **not** use the `alias` in `\hyphentextcquote{alias}...` (wasted so much time on this). `\hyphentextcquote` and the like are *multilingual* commands, and the first argument for them is supposed to be an *actual* language (as seen by e.g. `babel`). If it happens that the language chosen for `\hyphentextcquote` etc. also has a quote style alias with the same name, then the quote style will be applied.
- When you call `\setquotestyle[italic]{english}` (originating from `\DeclareQuoteStyle[italic]{english}...`) you force `csquotes` to **exit** "multilingual mode"; and then the language settings in `\hyphentextcquote{language}...` don't matter; the quote style from `\setquotestyle` takes priority. To go back to multilingual mode, use the starred `\setquotestyle*` (no arguments).

Some complication was encountered when looking for the customization of the block quote style; I tried `\unravel{}` around the `\hyphentextcquote` - that resulted with ~14000 steps, and `\mkblockquote` (which obviously has an influence, given the OP), didn't even show! What did show, however, was `\csq@bquote@iii`, the only command that calls it. From its [definition](https://github.com/fiesh/VroniPlag-Bericht-Generator/blob/15ace8c87cde3b8ce78a937f3744d19551a11707/csquotes.sty#L1245), it's clear that there's no other way to edit the block quote style but to redefine `\mkblockquote`.

So that's what the new commands do:

- `\DeclareQuoteBlockStyle` is the same as `\DeclareQuoteStyle`, but it has an extra first optional argument, where we can specify a definition for a `\mkblockquote` as a "style"; this gets saved under a name derived from the `[variant]{style}` names (so it should be able to handle multiple styles);  and
- `\setquoteblockstyle` is the same as `\setquotestyle`, but it also sets the saved "block style" definition as per `[variant]{style}` to `\mkblockquote` so its active; `\setquoteblockstyle*` also restores `\mkblockquote` to its original definition.

Note that once `\setquote(block)style` has properly set the quote style, then the style will also be applied via `\openautoquote`, if it is present in `\mkblockquote`, to block quotes! So, any additional formatting in `\mkblockquote` for block quotes will be added in *addition* to set style via `\openautoquote`; that is why I used `\bfseries` in there, so it can be seen on the MWE which covers what.

Well, hope I didn't misunderstood the manual, and I didn't code all this in vain `:)` Anyways, here - [csquotes_test.tex @gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/99aa7c8dfe5022ab4c40) - is a previous test file with some comments; and the final MWE is:

```
% pdflatex test.tex; biber test; pdflatex test.tex; pdflatex test.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage{unravel}

\usepackage[autostyle=tryonce,autopunct=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ieee, isbn=true, doi=false, url=true, defernumbers=true, sorting=nyt, firstinits=false, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[UKenglish,USenglish]{babel}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{yellow!10}

% start hacks:
\makeatletter
  % prepare vars
  \let\csq@oldblockstyle\mkblockquote
  \def\csq@newblockstyle{}
  % cmd to declare a quote and block style
  \newrobustcmd*{\DeclareQuoteBlockStyle}[2][]{%
    \let\if@safe@actives\iftrue
    \ifblank{#1}
      {\typeout{DQBS: 1 is blank}}
      {%\def\csq@newblockstyle{#1}% new variable; but cannot handle `#1` in '#1', which \mkblockquote below needs
       % save for \mkblockquote
       \renewcommand{\csq@newblockstyle}[4]{#1}
       \typeout{DQBS: 1 is \meaning\csq@newblockstyle} %#1}%
      }
    \DeclareQuoteBlockStyleI#2%
  }
  % helper to extract the names
  \newrobustcmd*{\DeclareQuoteBlockStyleI}[2][]{%
    \begingroup
    \let\if@safe@actives\iftrue
    \ifblank{#1}
      {\typeout{DQBSI: 1 is blank, 2 is '#2'}%
      % \DeclareQuoteStyle#2 % cannot, args are gobbled, must use low-level now:
      \edef\csq@tempa{#2}
      }%
      {\typeout{DQBSI: 1 is '#1', 2 is '#2'}%
      %\DeclareQuoteStyle[1]#2\expandafter % cannot...
      \edef\csq@tempa{#2/#1}
      }
    % \let assigned vars should survive renewcommand of @newblockstyle;
    % but must be global, else other code can't see it:
    \global\cslet{csq@blkstyle@\csq@tempa}{\csq@newblockstyle}
    \typeout{Command: csq@blkstyle@\csq@tempa -> \expandafter\meaning\csname csq@blkstyle@\csq@tempa \endcsname}
    \@ifnextchar[%] % continue w/ low-level
      {\csq@declareqstyle@i}
      {\csq@declareqstyle@i[]}%
  }
  % cmd to set also block style when changing quote style
  \newrobustcmd*{\setquoteblockstyle}{%
    \@ifstar
      {\typeout{setquoteblockstyle has to restore}%}
      \let\mkblockquote\csq@oldblockstyle % restore block quote style
      \setquotestyle*} % here the star is gobbled, so must re-add it manually!
      {\@ifnextchar[%]
         {\typeout{setquoteblockstyle has two} %'#1' and '#2'}} "! Illegal parameter number in definition"
         \setquoteblockstyleI}
         {\typeout{setquoteblockstyle has only one} %'#1'}}%
         \setquoteblockstyleI}
      }%
      %\setquotestyle% proceed with original; here will also claim the * correctly and will work - but makes the \@ifstar/\@ifnextchar switch above incorrect, so must include it everywhere separately
  }
  % helper - so we can capture the args
  \def\setquoteblockstyleI[#1]#2{%
    \ifblank{#1}
      { \edef\csq@tempa{#2}%
        \csletcs{mkblockquote}{csq@blkstyle@\csq@tempa}%
        \setquotestyle{#2}%
      }
      { \edef\csq@tempa{#2/#1}%
        \typeout{mkblockquote was \meaning\mkblockquote}%
        \csletcs{mkblockquote}{csq@blkstyle@\csq@tempa}%
        \typeout{mkblockquote csq@blkstyle@\csq@tempa, is now \meaning\mkblockquote}% undefined
        \setquotestyle[#1]{#2}%
      }%
  }
\makeatother
% end hacks

% the original use: (now as first opt arg in \DeclareQuoteBlockStyle)
% \renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{\openautoquote{\itshape##1##2}##4##3\closeautoquote}

% \DeclareQuoteBlockStyle[]% leave like this for #1 blank...
\DeclareQuoteBlockStyle[%
  \openautoquote{\bfseries#1#2}#4#3\closeautoquote% \mkblockquote contents (block style)
]%
[italics]{english}%
[\itshape]
[\normalfont]
  {>\textquoteleft}
  {\textquoteright<}
  [0.05em]
  {>{>}\textquotedblleft}
  {\textquotedblright<{<}}
\DeclareQuoteAlias[italics]{english}{ITenglish}


\begin{document}

\hyphenquote{UKenglish}{quote with UK English hyphenation}

% \ExecuteQuoteOptions{english=italics} % only in preamble!
% \setkeys{csq}{english=italics} % only in preamble!
% \setquotestyle{debug} % ok
% \setquotestyle[italics]{english}
\setquoteblockstyle[italics]{english}

\textcquote[1]{knuth:ct:a}{formal quote}

\hyphentextcquote{UKenglish}[1]{knuth:ct:a}{formal quote \enquote{with UK} English hyphenation}

\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\hyphentextcquote{UKenglish}[1]{knuth:ct:a}{formal quote "with UK" English hyphenation}

\MakeAutoQuote{«}{»}
\hyphentextcquote{UKenglish}[1]{knuth:ct:a}{formal quote «with UK» English hyphenation}

\hyphenblockcquote{UKenglish}[1]{knuth:ct:a}{A long formal quote with UK English hyphenation which \enquote{happens to be longer than three lines}, thus, is typeset as a block quote. This text is just to make it long enough. This text is just to make it long enough. This text is just to make it long enough.}


% \setquotestyle*
\setquoteblockstyle*

\hyphenblockcquote{english}[1]{knuth:ct:a}{ A long formal quote with UK English hyphenation which \enquote{happens to be longer than three lines} and, thus, is typeset as a block quote. This text is just to make it long enough. This text is just to make it long enough. This text is just to make it long enough.}
\printbibliography[sorting=none]

\end{document}
```