# Unable to change quote type in french

Tags: babel, csquotes, french, babel-french

I'm using `csquotes` and writing in French. I'd like to set the quotation marks as they are in english, and [I don't want to use this method ``` `` ```](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39285/whats-the-advantage-of-using-csquotes-over-using-an-editors-auto-replacement-f). I tried changing the variant but it always gives me guillemets.
Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[french = quotes]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\enquote{Bonjour}

\end{document}
```

**Expected output :**

[image]

**Actual output :**

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage[style=english]{csquotes}` should do the trick.

Comment: Indeed, but then why don't the variations, documented in the manual, work ?

Comment: At '10.9 Miscellaneous Notes about the Predefined Styles' in the manual it says: "All variants of the `french` style use spaced out guillemets as outer marks. The style variant `quotes` uses double quotes as inner marks.", so I guess both variants look the same on this level... But as long as babel sets the language to French, csquotes will use a French quoting style anyway, so to use an English style the easiest solution that came to mind was to use `style=english`.

Comment: I couldn't find a duplicate of this question, would you accept this if I posted as an answer, or would you like to wait and see if there is a different solution?

Comment: That extract of the manual answers my question so, yes feel free

Comment: Don't forget to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` when typesetting French.

Comment: Why would you want such a thing in the first place ? Are you not aware of french typography ? See the "Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale" for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the csquotes manual it says at section '10.9 Miscellaneous Notes about the Predefined Styles':

"All variants of the `french` style use spaced out guillemets as outer marks. The style variant `quotes` uses double quotes as inner marks." Which means both variants look the same on the outer level.

You can change the style to the default English quotation marks with `\usepackage[style=english]{csquotes}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[style=english]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\enquote{Bonjour}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(As egreg noted, fontenc should be used. And on up-to-date LaTeX installations utf8 is the standard, so inputenc can be omitted.)